# Select all users policies in code which are set in startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core app I'm setting up a policy for permisson:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => {
        policy.RequireRole(Configuration.GetSection("SecuritySettings:ADGroup").Get<string[]>());        
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });

    options.AddPolicy("User", policy => {
        policy.RequireRole(Configuration.GetSection("SecuritySettings2:ADGroup2").Get<string[]>());        
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
```

This works so far for the controller authorization:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
```

But now I would like to check again which policies does the user have besides, maybe he has more than one policy which I would like to determine in the mdethod:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    List<string> allowedStatus = new List<string>(); 

    if (User.IsInRole("User")) { 
        allowedStatus.Add("DK");
    }

    if (await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "User")) { 
        allowedStatus.Add("DK");
    } 
}
```

Can someone tell me how to get an array of all the user's policies? I am using `services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`;

Comment: `how to get an array of all the user's policies?` Can you clarify more about the actual scenario that requires getting authorization policies that current user meets? Not user's groups?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the constructor I had also to add the IAuthorizationService authorizationService object so that later in the code I can use the await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync command.

Not sure if this is the correct way, but it works. Besides, I created a static class to return a list of possible events my user is able to do. The method head looks like this:

```
public static async Task<List<string>> getStatusAsync(ClaimsPrincipal User, IAuthorizationService _authorizationService){
```

or when you want to call it like a non asnyc method like this:

```
public static List<string> getStatus(ClaimsPrincipal User, IAuthorizationService _authorizationService)
        {
            List<string> list = getStatusAsync(User, _authorizationService).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            return list;
        }
```

As requested:

```
    public static async Task<List<string>> getStatusAsync(ClaimsPrincipal User, IAuthorizationService _authorizationService){

        List<string> allowedStatus = new List<string>();

        if( (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "SccmAdmin")).Succeeded || (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "SccmDeviceAa")).Succeeded){
            allowedStatus.Add("BE");
        }

        if( (await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "SccmDeviceBe")).Succeeded){
            allowedStatus.Add("BE");
        }

        return allowedStatus;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the getStatusAsync method?

Comment: Hi @JohnM, is added